# Результат при использовании time() в константе

Tags: php, datetime, время, unixtimestamp

Вопрос такой, при использовании функции `time()` (возвращает `unix` время) внутри константы какой будет результат? Ну тоесть вернётся текущее время на момент вызова константы, или то время, которое было при её инициализации в `define()`?

```
define('TIMENOW', time());

// Спустя много строк кода...

echo TIMENOW;
```

Comment: Ну сделай задержку в 3 секунды `sleep(3)` и посмотри.

Comment: Скорее всего там будет время на тот момент, когда интерпретатор обработал этот `define`. Но надо проверять.

Comment: @CrazyElf серьёзно, вот прям надо проверять? И какой же тип данных возвращает функция time(), чтобы они даже гипотетически могли меняться со временем?

Comment: @Ипатьев Я на `php` программировал последний раз то ли 15, то ли 25 лет назад, поэтому не могу быть 100% уверен в своих советах по нему ))

Answer (score 0):

В отличие от сказок про Гарри Поттера и Золотую Рыбку, в программировании отсутствует такое понятие как магия. Все происходит очень скучно и материально. В частности, в программировании нет такого понятия, как "время". Если догадаться посмотреть описание функции `time()` в документации, то окажется, что она возвращает не какое-то "время", а всего лишь число. Цифры. И вот эти-то цифры и присваиваются константе. Если функция на момент вызова вернула значение 1701758466, то константа получает значение 1701758466. И возвращает значение 1701758466.

Вот пример:

```
define('TIMENOW', time()); // 1701758466

var_dump(time()); // 1701758466
var_dump(TIMENOW); // 1701758466

sleep(3); // задержка 3 секунды

var_dump(time()); // 1701758469 (тут мы видим что прошло 3 секунды)
var_dump(TIMENOW); // 1701758466 (тут видно что значение константы сохранилось)
```

Comment: В ответе укажите, пожалуйста, что вам помогло конкретно. т.е. представьте ответ. А также, если есть ответ, то вы можете поставить метку решенной задачи у своего вопроса.

Comment: @Volk, метку поставить не могу, сайт пишет только через 2 дня смогу. Ответ отредактирую

Comment: Нет никакого "состояния данных". Есть только сами данные. Если ты положил в кошелек 5 рублей, то в нем лежит 5 рбулей, а не "состояние пяти рублей"

Comment: @Ипатьев, спасибо, коллега. Не так выразился, под "состоянием данных" я имел ввиду значение (данные) константы, которые мы положили один раз при инициализации, и больше изменить не можем, а можем лишь  их просмотреть (ну тоесть посмотреть их состояние на момент инициализации)

Comment: И при чем здесь "изменить не можем"? То есть если результат time() присвоить переменной, а не константе, то она будет изменять свое значение со временем, серньёзно?

Comment: @Ипатьев, ну вместе с результатом функции будет меняться и значение переменной, которой присваивается результат функции. С переменными не проверял, но подозреваю что если вывести значение переменной, то выведется актуальное значение на момент вызова, а не на момент инициализации её самой.

Comment: Ну то есть если присвоить переменной значение 5 рублей, то со временем там само по себе окажется 10 рублей? Да это же золотая жила!

Comment: Я думал что каждый новый вызов переменной инициирует и обращение к функции, которая в свою очередь должна нам вернуть актуальные данные на момент вызова, а не на момент инициализации, поскольку time() возвращает каждый раз новое значение.

Comment: Вы переменной присваиваете не "функцию". А ЗНАЧЕНИЕ, которая она возвращает.